# Set up Protocol with Modal View Controller -> ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I have an initial `ViewController`, lets call it `HomeViewController`, that has a button which calls a modal view controller, lets call it `ModalViewController`. Inside that `ModalViewController` I have a table view with two sections. If you click on any cell from section 0 it sends information back to `HomeViewController` (this part I have working with Protocol). If you click on any of the cells from section 1 it pushes to another view controller with options, lets call it `OptionsViewController`. Here is where it gets tricky for me. If you click any of those options, dismiss `OptionsViewController` and close  `ModalViewcontroller` and send that information to `HomeViewController`, just like `ModalViewController` to `HomeViewController`. I have tried to set up a protocol similar to the one in `ModalViewController` but it is never called.

`OptionsViewController` protocol & .h file

```
@protocol OptionsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) optionsInfo:(NSArray *)optionsViewArray;

@end

@interface OptionsViewController : UITableViewController
@property (retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sendArray;
@end
```

OptionsViewController.m where it's called to pop off the stack.

```
{
    [self dismissOptionsView];
}
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Send Array: %@", self.sendArray);
    [[self delegate] optionsInfo:sendArray];
}
-(void)dismissOptionsView
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Inside ModalViewController.h

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) sendInformation:(NSArray *)infoArray;
@end

@interface ModalViewController : UITableViewController <ConditionsViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    UISearchBar *searchDrugBar;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchDrugBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *infoArray;
@end
```

ModalViewController.m where OptionsInfo is supposed to come in.

```
-(void) optionsInfo:(NSArray *)optionsViewArray
{
    //IT NEVER REACHES HERE :(
    NSLog(@"HERE");
    self.infoArray = optionsViewArray;
    NSLog(@"Finished");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Has any one has done something similar like this or knows the solution to this? Any information, link, guidance and etc. to the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate in your OptionsViewController below:-

In your `OptionsViewController.m` Include below line on your method

```
 [self setDelegate:ModalViewController];
```

Comment: below which method? `[self dismissOptionsView];` or `[[self delegate] optionsInfo:sendArray];`. Also using `ModalViewController` means that I would have to `#import "ModalViewController.h"` inside OptionsViewController.h, correct? I thought we weren't allowed to do this with Protocols, something about recursive ownership or something like that.

Comment: Yes Correct you have to import ModalViewController.h, Because until unless you won't set the delegate. Your method will not get called

Comment: Done. Now I am getting an error `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OptionsViewControllerDelegate', did you mean 'UISplitViewControllerDelegate' ? I am getting that error on the @interface for ModalViewController && on `@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<OptionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate1;` Any idea what thats about?

Comment: I think you need to declare your property of delegate in OptionsViewController.h like this @property (retain) id<OptionsViewControllerDelegate > delegate;

Comment: I fixed that error, had to put the protocols above the #imports. That fixed the error but now when I run it, it still does not NSLog or get to the optionInfo method.

Comment: I can't use `delegate` instead of `delegate1` because in ModalViewController I am using id delegate for HomeViewController -- `@property (retain) id delegate;` inside ModalViewController.